# How to call another object within Pyspark UDF function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a `class Hello` with a few methods

I would like to create a hello object within a UDF pyspark function, such as:

```
def foo_generation(query_params):
  query_obj = Hello()
  foo = query_obj.hello_method(query_params)
  return foo
​
spark.udf.register("foo_generation", foo_generation)
df = df.withColumn("foo", F.expr("foo_generation(query_param_ES)"))
```

This doesn't appear to be working.
How should I generate a Hello object in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf(returnType=StringType())
def foo_generation(str):
  query_obj = Hello()
  foo = query_obj.hello_method(str)
  return foo

df = df.withColumn("foo", F.expr("foo_generation(str)"))
```